# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sinch-android-rtc from loader dalvik.system

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, service

I unexpectedly received the below error while trying to run my android application on the phone. Essentially in the application, it makes a call to messageservice so that I am able to run my instant messaging. I am using Sinch for android to handle my instant messaging.

Below is the log cat message:

```
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1610
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sinch-android-rtc from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.dooba.beta-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.dooba.beta-1, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.natives.jni.UserAgentFactory.<clinit>(UserAgentFactory.java:9)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.ServiceFactory.createUserAgent(ServiceFactory.java:44)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.DefaultSinchClient.<init>(DefaultSinchClient.java:155)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.InternalSinchClientFactory.createSinchClient(InternalSinchClientFactory.java:14)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.sinch.android.rtc.DefaultSinchClientBuilder.build(DefaultSinchClientBuilder.java:95)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.dooba.beta.MessageService.startSinchClient(MessageService.java:66)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.dooba.beta.MessageService.onStartCommand(MessageService.java:56)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2702)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-08 00:34:31.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1610):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is the MessageService activity:

```
public class MessageService extends Service implements SinchClientListener {

    private static final String APP_KEY = "xxxxx";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "xxxxx";
    private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";
    private final MessageServiceInterface serviceInterface = new MessageServiceInterface();
    private SinchClient sinchClient = null;
    private MessageClient messageClient = null;
    private String currentUserId;
    private LocalBroadcastManager broadcaster;
    private Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("com.dooba.beta.MessagingActivity1");

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();

        if (currentUserId != null && !isSinchClientStarted()) {
            startSinchClient(currentUserId);
        }

        broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void startSinchClient(String username) {
        sinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(this).userId(username).applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET).environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

        sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(this);

        sinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
        sinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);

        sinchClient.checkManifest();
        sinchClient.start();
    }

    private boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
        return sinchClient != null && sinchClient.isStarted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", false);
        broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        sinchClient = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("success", true);
        broadcaster.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        client.startListeningOnActiveConnection();
        messageClient = client.getMessageClient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
        sinchClient = null;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return serviceInterface;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client, ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
    }

    public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
            messageClient.send(message);
        }
    }

    public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            messageClient.addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (messageClient != null) {
            messageClient.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        sinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
        sinchClient.terminate();
    }

    public class MessageServiceInterface extends Binder {
        public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
            MessageService.this.sendMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
        }

        public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            MessageService.this.addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }

        public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            MessageService.this.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }

        public boolean isSinchClientStarted() {
            return MessageService.this.isSinchClientStarted();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update
Screens of the library added

[image]

[image]

![enter image description here][3]

Update 3
[image]

```
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.ServiceFactory.createUserAgent(ServiceFactory.java:44)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.DefaultSinchClient.<init>(DefaultSinchClient.java:157)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.client.InternalSinchClientFactory.createSinchClient(InternalSinchClientFactory.java:14)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at com.sinch.android.rtc.DefaultSinchClientBuilder.build(DefaultSinchClientBuilder.java:95)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at com.dooba.beta.MessageService.startSinchClient(MessageService.java:56)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at com.dooba.beta.MessageService.onStartCommand(MessageService.java:40)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2490)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sinch-android-rtc: findLibrary returned null
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
10-09 18:27:08.450: E/AndroidRuntime(999):  at com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.natives.jni.UserAgentFactory.<clinit>(UserAgentFactory.java:9)
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.co
```

m/5Kx3e.png

Comment: its a problem with your library, your app cant see your .so, i think

Comment: would you suggest me to redownload the sinch library? or what other proposal do you have in mind?

Comment: no, try looking for the instruction of setting up the sinch library make sure you didnt miss some part. sorry im not familiar with android studio.

Comment: Thanks. I am not using android studio though, but eclipse, could this be the heart of the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to copy the sinch libraries to your project, please see the [sinch client for android documentation](http://tutorial.sinch.com/android-messaging-tutorial/#setting-up-the-sinch-client)

download [the sinch android sdk zip](http://download.sinch.com/android/3.3.4/sinch-android-rtc-3.3.4.zip) , copy the contents of `libs` folder into the `libs` under your project root.

clean and rebuild the project. Before testing the apk, open the apk as a zip and make sure .so files are in `lib\*\` folder;

if you are having trouble getting eclipse to properly package the app, [please consider using sinch's documentation and use android studio as they suggest](http://tutorial.sinch.com/android-messaging-tutorial/#setting-up-the-sinch-client)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Following your suggestions, I removed the previous sinch library and related folders, and replaced them with the one you suggested. I have then clean and rebuild the project. How do i open the apk as a zip? I am not too familiar with android studio and most of my files are eclipse, the platform I am quite familiar with. I am not sure how I would port over

Comment: apk is just a zip file...use winzip or 7z or any other zip software. This is just to make sure you apk has those .so libs inside it.

Comment: I unzip the apk , and the .so files seems to be located inside the libs folder. I have been struggling with this issue since a while, and is extremly confused. If I send you the project, would it be too much too ask to quickly look at it?

Comment: try running it, and update your question with results. we can try fix any other issues you see. other users may chip in if they already use this library...i haven't used sinch before.

Comment: how would I import everything to android studio?

Comment: get the new Android Studio v0.8.11 , it will import eclipse project directly...just point your project folder, AS will do the rest.

Comment: thank you. Do you by chance know where the SDK manager exe is located inside android studio, because I want to run it as an administrator since I cant seem to install the updates

Comment: its under `Tools -> Andoird -> SDK Manager` or keyboard short cut `ctrl + shift + a`, type `sdk manager`, click it.

Comment: if you are looking for the file itself, do a file search in explorer. location depends on your installation path

Comment: Thanks Recieving the following error: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0-rc1 really frustrating

Comment: Try this sample https://github.com/sinch/android-messaging-tutorial-skeleton to get familiar with AS and sinch

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Sadly, I reach the same error even with android studio -     Process: com.sinch.messagingtutorial.app, PID: 1964
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load sinch-android-rtc from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sinch.messagingtutorial.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.sinch.messagingtutorial.app-1, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

Comment: Hi ashoke thank you so much for your support thus far. As far my initial question goes, I have feeling that the library files were imporperly added, and for your courteously I have included pictures of the eclipse IDE (so you can see whats in the library), and the library folder that eclipse provided.

Comment: can you show the output of `jar tvf <your apk>`, this will simply show the list of files inside your apk.

Comment: sorry for this dummany question but how would you show the output of jar tvf <your apk>?

Comment: open a command prompt, `cd` to the directory where your apk is, type in `jar tfv apk_file_name`, post here the screenshot image or just copy-paste here the output you see.

Comment: sorry maybe i am a novice at this but inside the bin folder in cmd i am declaring "jar tfv Dooba Beta Testing" and is getting the error that "jar is not operable program or batch file" thanks for your patience and for your courtesouy I have also included the picture of the apk unzip under the update section of my initial post

Comment: ANy suggestions. i would really appreciate

Comment: your apk zip screesnhot does not show the `libs` folder !! we need to fix that; Right-click project in eclipse `-> properties -> java build path -> libraries` manually add your libs folder there. Then, click `Order and Export` in the same screen. If unchecked, select the `libs` you just added.  Then, Click `Project -> Clean` , rebuild, open the apk again with zip, see if `libs` folder shows up.

Comment: Hi, please look into update 3. I have followed your advice and wondering if this was correct as I am still getting an error

Comment: inside your apk, under the `lib` folder do you see the `armeabi` and other folders? And inside these, the .so files ?

Comment: Yes I do, which is what I find most troubling. I notice this is getting a bit off topic, and I have redirected a new post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292239/exceptionininitializererror-findlibrary-returned-null